# What is missing in Python Flask app that build is failing?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

what could be the build failure reason? I tried different versions of MarkupSafe but still its getting failed. Tried running different branches too, all builds are getting failed.
Does it has any version issues? Are there any other libraries required? Using postgres for db.

```
-----> Python app detected
     !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.6.12
           Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
    -----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
    -----> Installing python-3.6.4
    -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
    -----> Installing SQLite3
    -----> Installing requirements with pip
           Collecting alembic==0.9.6
             Downloading alembic-0.9.6.tar.gz (998 kB)
           Collecting arrow==0.12.0
             Downloading arrow-0.12.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
           Collecting blinker==1.4
             Downloading blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111 kB)
           Collecting click==6.7
             Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
           Collecting dateparser==0.6.0
             Downloading dateparser-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
           Collecting dominate==2.3.1
             Downloading dominate-2.3.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
           Collecting feedparser==5.2.1
             Downloading feedparser-5.2.1.tar.bz2 (192 kB)
           Collecting Flask==0.12.2
             Downloading Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
           Collecting Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
             Downloading Flask-Bootstrap-3.3.7.1.tar.gz (456 kB)
           Collecting Flask-Login==0.4.1
             Downloading Flask-Login-0.4.1.tar.gz (14 kB)
           Collecting Flask-Mail==0.9.1
             Downloading Flask-Mail-0.9.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
           Collecting Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
             Downloading Flask_Migrate-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
           Collecting Flask-PyMongo==0.5.1
             Downloading Flask_PyMongo-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
           Collecting Flask-Script==2.0.6
             Downloading Flask-Script-2.0.6.tar.gz (43 kB)
           Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
             Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
           Collecting Flask-WTF==0.14.2
             Downloading Flask_WTF-0.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
           Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1
             Downloading gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
           Collecting itsdangerous==0.24
             Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46 kB)
           Collecting Jinja2==2.10
             Downloading Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
           Collecting Mako==1.0.7
             Downloading Mako-1.0.7.tar.gz (564 kB)
           Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0
             Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz (14 kB)
               ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
                command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uzscpaqz/MarkupSafe/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uzscpaqz/MarkupSafe/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-jupo_kuh
                    cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uzscpaqz/MarkupSafe/
               Complete output (5 lines):
               Traceback (most recent call last):
                 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
                 File "/tmp/pip-install-uzscpaqz/MarkupSafe/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
                   from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
               ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'
               ----------------------------------------
           ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
     !     Push failed
```

Comment: `Feature` is no longer part of `setuptools`.  You need to downgrade versions or find another solution:  https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading MarkupSafe to the latest release:

```
$ pip install --upgrade MarkupSafe
```